# How to add caption field for every image preview and post all caption through one submit button

Tags: php

This is my code I want to add one input field for every image preview and save it to db.. the field is coming but I'm not getting any data.. can anyone suggest how can I post them???

```
$fetch_imgid=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM attempt010 where link='$rand'");
$fetch_imgid->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC);
$fetch_imgid->execute();
?>
<ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list" id="previewImg">
    <?php
    while($row = $fetch_imgid->fetch()):
        $delid = $row['id'];
        //echo $row['id'].' '.$row['name'].'<br/>';?>
        <li id="image_li_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="ui-sortable-handle" data-image-id="<?php echo $delid; ?>">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="float:none;" class="image_link"><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" alt=""></a>
        <input type="submit" class="del_btn" value="Delete Image" />
        <input type="text" id="cap" name="cap[]" placeholder="Enter Caption Here" />
        <input type="hidden" id="cap_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
    <?php

    endWhile;
    ?>

</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Add Caption" name="addcap" /> <?php include('addcap.php'); ?>
```

and this is addcap.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
if(isset($_POST['addcap'])){
    foreach($_POST['cap'])
    {
            $imgcap = $_POST['cap'];
            if($imgcap!=empty())
            {
                try
                {
                    $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=newimg","root","");
                    $sql=$con->prepare("UPDATE attempt010 SET caption='$imgcap' WHERE id='$cap_id'");
                    $sql->execute();
                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="hidden" id="cap_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
```

Must have unique id. You can't send multiple fields with same id. You will get only last one.

For example:

```
$fetch_imgid=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM attempt010 where link='$rand'");
$fetch_imgid->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC);
$fetch_imgid->execute();
?>
<form action="addcap.php" method="post">
<ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list" id="previewImg">
    <?php
    $id_array="";
    while($row = $fetch_imgid->fetch()):
        $id_array = $id_array.$row['id'].",";
    $delid = $row['id'];
    //echo $row['id'].' '.$row['name'].'<br/>';?>
    <li id="image_li_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="ui-sortable-handle" data-image-id="<?php echo $delid; ?>">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="float:none;" class="image_link"><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" alt=""></a>
    <input type="text" id="cap_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" placeholder="Enter Caption Here" />
<?php

endWhile;
$id_array = substr($id_array, 0, -1);
?>
<input type="hidden" id="cap_ids" value="<?php echo $id_array ; ?>" />

</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Add Caption" name="addcap" /> 
</form>


<!--addcap.php-->

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
if(isset($_POST['addcap'])){
    if(isset($_POST['cap_ids'])){
        $ids_array = explode(",", $_POST['cap_ids']);
        foreach($ids_array as $ids)
        {
                $idcap = 'cap_'.$ids;
                $imgcap = $_POST[$idcap];
                if($imgcap!=empty())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        $con=new 
PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=newimg","root","");
                        $query = "UPDATE attempt010 SET 
caption='$imgcap' WHERE id='$ids'";
                        echo $query;
                        $sql=$con->prepare($query);
                        $sql->execute();
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This code looks like it can't work. Because you have submit and form handling code in same page. The idea behind form is to post data to different page(set in form action) and this page will do something with this data and display results to the user. For your example to work make form in your first file like:

```
<form action="addcap.php">
    <inputs here>
</form>
```

Nowadays it is common that database operations are done asynchronic on server side, when user can continue using the page/app. 
So learn how to use jQuery and AJAX. Maybe nodeJS or other new stuff.

Comment: I'll post all code for you. I've a good day today ;) Wait a second.

Comment: I've edited the code few times so try newest version. And of course split the code the way it was before. Into two files.

Comment: used `if($imgcap!='')` instead of `if($imgcap!=empty())` now there's no error but it's not updating the table...

Comment: To be fair all your code is quite messy. But...Try to echo $id_array after it is created. Then echo $_POST['cap_ids']. Then check $_POST['cap_'.$ids];

Comment: thanks for pointing it out... but... now it's showing ` cap_` as an undefined index...

Comment: still not working... it's going to addcap.php... but not updating the field

Comment: So you are close ;) Print your sql statement on the screen and check it in your database directly. I edited the answer. Remember to be patient and always check where exactly your app is not working. If sql statement is ok, then your database privillages are not enough for update.

Comment: Mayby field id is not string but int. then change sql to UPDATE attempt010 SET 
caption='$imgcap' WHERE id=$ids

Comment: the query is working properly... I was checking this `if(isset($_POST['cap_ids']))` if statement have issues... I was echoing in every block but here I'm not getting anything...

Comment: If query is created corectly then your next line is the problem:
$sql=$con->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();
Check documentation for this.

Comment: It's not getting the capids in `if(isset($_POST['cap_ids']))`.... because if I remove that is statement and the foreach after it then I just make two variables with sample values and changed the query with `$sql=$con->prepare("UPDATE attempt010 SET caption='$b' WHERE id='$a'");` then it's updating the values...

Comment: Try new simplier version. Without delete button.

Comment: Ok. So go back. Open source code of first page and check value of <input type="hidden" id="cap_ids"

Comment: So you don't have field 'id' in your attempt010  table. Start with this and then slowly move on.

Comment: I have id field in attempt010 table... image deletion is working perfectly.. I'm deleting image with the ids...

Comment: C'mon... Get ids from table. Print them. Check. Create string with all ids in loop(separated by commas). Print. Check. Send all ids with form. Open source code of the page. Check. Get them in addcap.php. Print. Check. And so on...

Comment: Start with something that is working. And go one step at a time.